# JQuery Get Element Name On Html Table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table. 
It's keep product name, amount and price..

When I want to change amount 2-3-4 or another number it's change just first row.

How can I change the result for all rows

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Product Name 1 </td>
    <td><input type="text" id = "amount" value="1"></td>
    <td id="price">55</td>
    <td id="result"><!-- Here is 55*1 (amount) --></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Product Name 2 </td>
    <td><input type="text" id = "amount" value="1"></td>
    <td id="price">65</td>
    <td id="result"><!-- Here is 65*1 (amount) --></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Product Name 3 </td>
    <td><input type="text" id = "amount" value="1"></td>
    <td id="price">23</td>
    <td id="result"><!-- Here is 23*1 (amount) --></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $('#amount').keyup(function () { 
        var amount= $("#amount").val();
        var price = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.price').text();
        var result = amount * price;
        $("#result").html(result).show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Shh.. Id should be unique..!

Comment: Id should be unique, neccessary, and must

Comment: Duplicated IDs, `miktar` undefined

Comment: I'm try id="price[]" and id="amount[]". there is dinamicly.. 
But i cant get $("#price[]").val();

Comment: the problem with duplicate id's is that the page searches for the from the top. if you have several elements with same id, the browser will start searching from the top, find the first element matching the id and stop there. so either use different id's or use same id's but in different contexts

Comment: I don't know there is how many rows.. It's change by user..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**IDs must be unique.** You can use class instead.

*HTML*

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Product Name 1</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="amount" value="1" />
        </td>
        <td class="price">55</td>
        <td class="result">
            <!-- Here is 55*1 (amount) -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Product Name 2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="amount" value="1" />
        </td>
        <td class="price">65</td>
        <td class="result">
            <!-- Here is 65*1 (amount) -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Product Name 3</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="amount" value="1" />
        </td>
        <td class="price">23</td>
        <td class="result">
            <!-- Here is 23*1 (amount) -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*JS*

```
$('input.amount').keyup(function () {
    var amount = +$(this).val();  //Here use '+' to convert to number
    var price = +$(this).closest('tr').find('td.price').text();
    var result = amount * price; //Here miktar is undefined 
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td.result').html(result).show();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TmKx2/)

Comment: I have one question :) <tr><td id="total"><!-- All rows total. --></td></tr> How can I change it? :)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use classes (IDs must be unique, as stated in the comments):

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>Product Name 1 </td>
     <td><input type="text" class = "amount" value="1"></td>
     <td class="price">55</td>
     <td class="result"><!-- Here is 55*1 (amount) --></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Product Name 2 </td>
     <td><input type="text" class = "amount" value="1"></td>
     <td class="price">65</td>
     <td class="result"><!-- Here is 65*1 (amount) --></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Product Name 3 </td>
     <td><input type="text" class = "amount" value="1"></td>
     <td class="price">23</td>
     <td class="result"><!-- Here is 23*1 (amount) --></td>
   </tr>
</table>

<script>
$('.amount').keyup(function () { 
    var amount= $(this).val();
    var price = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.price').text();
    var result = amount * price;
    $(this).closest('tr').children('td.result').html(result).show();
});
</script>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/9qVCM/)

UPDATE:

HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>Product Name 1 </td>
     <td><input type="text" class = "amount" value="1"></td>
     <td class="price">55</td>
     <td class="result"><!-- Here is 55*1 (amount) --></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Product Name 2 </td>
     <td><input type="text" class = "amount" value="1"></td>
     <td class="price">65</td>
     <td class="result"><!-- Here is 65*1 (amount) --></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Product Name 3 </td>
     <td><input type="text" class = "amount" value="1"></td>
     <td class="price">23</td>
     <td class="result"><!-- Here is 23*1 (amount) --></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan="3">Total</td>
     <td id="total"><!-- Total --></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.amount').keyup(function () { 
    var amount= $(this).val();
    var price = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.price').text();
    var result = amount * price;
    $(this).closest('tr').children('td.result').text(result).show();
    var total = 0;
    $(".result").each(function() {
        var val = parseFloat($(this).text());
        if (!isNaN(val)) {
            total += val;
        }
    });
    $("#total").text(total === 0 ? "" : total);
});
```

New fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/9qVCM/1)

Comment: Thank you. It's done. I have one question :) <tr><td id="total"><!-- All rows total. --></td></tr> How can I change it? :)